# Phonetic help for 'Frobenius'

Tags: pronunciation

My intuition says ['fʁɔbɪnjuːs] but not sure about it.

BTW, The person in question is 'Ferdinand Georg Frobenius' (the mathematician).

Comment: Would you mind telling us why you don't visit, say, Youtube and play a Frobenius-themed video with an Anglophone mathematician as the speaker (if you want British or U.S. pronunciation) or a vid with a Germanophone mathematician (for German pronunciation)?

Comment: 'Frobenius Mathematik' ----> returned nothing.  Also 'Frobenius Mathematiker' returned nothing. 'Frobenius' itself returns English or other languages videos (no German). Got any particular video in mind?

Comment: I tend to pronounce that guy [fʁɔ'beːnjus]

Comment: "frobenius pronunciation" and "frobenius aussprache" yield several hits at Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**/fʁoˈbeːniʊs/**
(primary stress on the second syllable)

The *r* is more fricative, although a slightly rolling /ʀ/ is appropriate for more articulate pronunciation (e.g. when speaking in front of a larger audience without PA system). However, in some rural regions in the northwest, in the south of Germany as well as in Austria and Switzerland, natives will roll it stronger, like /ʀ/ or even /r/.

/ˈfɛʁdinant ˈgeːɔʁk fʁoˈbeːniʊs/

(In Ferdinand, the r is often slurred away completely, making it /ˈfɛɐ̯dinant/. Some people will pronounce the first syllable more like /feːɐ̯/.)

( See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen#R )

Comment: Dawg, I'm still trying to track down the cause of my IPA display problem in Chrome. Now in your Answer, I see all the IPA glyphs in your first, second, and third paragraph, but in your fourth, I see only rectangles. Have you used different fonts here, and if so, what are they?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Not sure if this is related, but my usual browser (Safari 6.0.4) seems to have problems with the SE text editor whenever I put in the 'non-syllabic' or any other symbol that modifies other characters (using IPA Palette 2.1.1 by Brian Hall) – seems to insert some non-printing characters that make a number of glyphs overlap… I'll re-edit it with Firefox, where this doesn't happen. Does it get better now?

Comment: Yes! I see all the IPA glyphs now and no more rectangles :)

Comment: Good. So Safari and Chrome cause trouble with this kind of IPA symbols. Mist.

Comment: Uhh, sorry, was tired last night and not paying attention. In my customary Firefox, the IPA glyphs were fine as always. Now in Chrome, rectangles in fourth paragraph again. I should probably file a bug about this with Google, but I can't get worked up about it enough to do so...

Comment: I just saw that the rendering problem with combining IPA  diacritics has been reported in 2009 as Issue 7391: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7391  Google is currently changing Chrome from using the WebKit rendering engine to their own one called Blink, which is expected to premiere with version 28 (June/July 2013). It's probably not going to get better before that. (My Safari overlapping problem, on the other hand, appears to be related to the font Consolas that my browser uses in the text editor of SE - it can be remedied by changing the CSS of the text editor…)

Answer (score 3):

The second syllable gets the stress, i.e. [fʀoːˈbeːni̯ʊs]. This is according to latin rules (penultimate syllable is stressed if long, otherwise the one before it) that are observed in the German pronunciation of Latin. Examples include Auˈsonius or Auˈrelius.

Comment: I agree with the stress on the second syllable, but I have the impression that the most common vowel in the first syllable is a _short closed_ o, that is, [fʀoˈbeːni̯ʊs] or [fʁoˈbeːni̯ʊs].

Comment: Surprisingly, as I just noted when looking for comparable cases, Frobenius is listed in _Duden Aussprachewörterbuch_ (3rd edition, 1990). The pronunciation is given as [froˈbeːni̯ʊs], so indeed with short o.

Answer (score 1):

Since Frobenius is a latinised name, the [traditional German pronunciaton of latin words](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Aussprache_des_Lateinischen) should apply: [ˈfʀoːbeːni̯ʊs] (with the usual variation of the pronunciaton of the letter r). This is also the pronunciaton I heard among mathematicians.